Import function from package file
My project structure is as follows:
package/
    module/
        __init__.py
        component.py
    main.py
script.py

In main.py I have: from module.component import something.
And in script.py I want to import a function (lets call it 'function') from main.py.
What is the correct way to do this?
(I keep getting module not found errors - different modules depending on how I execute python and from which directory)
I tried changing the working directory which didn't help.
I believe this is not quite the same situation as in How can I do relative imports in Python?, because script.py is not actually part of the package I'm working on.
In the end I could make everything work by simply adding 'package' to the path:
sys.path.insert(0, "package")

inside script.py.

the package is running fine by itself (on AWS Lambda)

This should be an [edit] not a comment; comments get deleted all the time.

What module isn't found? What import statement actually produces the error?

If your're trying to import something in main.py and run main.py it'll work.
If you want to call the same function but running script.py you need to import in main like this
from package.module.component import something

OR 

from .module.component import something

as your imports are relative to the script.py.
Hope this helps.
